# Writing objects from response body to a JSON file in cypress within an array

Tags: cypress

I have been testing on how to write a API response body to a file in fixture with Cypress.

```js
it('Write File Test', function() {
    cy.request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users/293')
        .then((resp) => {
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', resp.body);
        });
});
```

The file in fixture is not created initially. While running this test, the json file got created and response body stored in this format:

```js
{
 "userid": 293,
 "username": "ramondz",
 "isactive": "active",
 "email": "ramon.dz@test.com"
}
```

I want this object to be stored within an array inside the JSON file in this format:

```js
[
    {
     "userid": 293,
     "username": "ramondz",
     "isactive": "active",
     "email": "ramon.dz@test.com"
    }
]
```

Actually, I tried creating a json file in fixture with an empty body [] and then ran the test. The text in the file is overridden and I got the response body stored as an object always. I couldn't get within the square brackets.

Is there an option to store response body as an array of objects. Could please someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on if `resp.body` is string or object.

One of these should work

```js
it('Write File Test', function() {
    cy.request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users/293')
        .then((resp) => {
            const respArray = [resp.body];
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', respArray);
        });
});
```

```js
it('Write File Test', function() {
    cy.request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users/293')
        .then((resp) => {
            const respArray = JSON.stringify([resp.body]);
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', respArray);
        });
});
```

```js
it('Write File Test', function() {
    cy.request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users/293')
        .then((resp) => {
            const respArray = '[' + JSON.stringify(resp.body) + ']';
            cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', respArray);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
it('Write File Test', function () {
  cy.request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/users/293').then((resp) => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', '[', {flag: 'a+'})
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', resp.body, {flag: 'a+'})
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/writeFile.json', ']', {flag: 'a+'})
  })
})
```

`{flag: 'a+'}` will make sure that the new contents are appended to the file rather than replacing the existing content.